# Cannot print screen on Logitech K780 keyboard

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech K780 keyboard. 
When I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, I cannot print screen. 
The keyboard does not have a "Print Screen" button.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10 I'd suggest using.

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

That being said make sure your print screen option is enabled [image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at it ( the print screen function for the Logitech K780 wireless keyboard) as a screen snapshot, copy and paste... It doesn't open a separate window. It just copies it in memory and then you can paste it to the page your creating ( like a blank MS Office Word document etc ). First, make sure your Logitech k780 wireless keyboard is configured to the system you are using (iOS (fn + i), Mac OS X (fn + o) or Windows (fn + p)... to do this press the appropriate shortcut for 3 seconds and the LED light of the 'seleted channel (1,2,3) will light up. Once that's configured, It should work if you press & hold the "fn" button, then press & hold the "del" button, release... then to "paste" the screen you've copied, go to the page you'd like to copy it to, use the Right-click button of your mouse and choose "paste" or use "ctrl" + "v". You can also read about the Logitech keyboard [https://www.logitech.com/assets/64567/k780-setup-guide.pdf] Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On my Logitech keyboard, it is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Took forever but I finally got it. This works if you're using it on an iMac though! Make sure your keyboard is connected via USB (idk how to do this with bluetooth).
Settings app > Keyboard > Screenshots
If you click it twice, you can edit it to make it whatever you want. My screenshot buttons are "ctrl + 1" Hope this helps, because I've been searching forever and finally got it.